# Array inserting only one row

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to export my database in excel using php. but the while loop is only inserting one row of values in the array and exported excel file will only have one only row of data.

I'm using a nested loop for table callback to insert it's data if it's not empty that is. So, basically there is two databases of values being exported to one excel file. First the data is is being stored in an array and then it is exported as an excel file.

Here's the code :

```
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM leads";
   $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
   $data = array();
    while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
    if ($row1["status"] == "1") 
    {
    $status = "New";
    }
    if ($row1["status"] == "2") 
    {
    $status = "Assigned";
    }
    if ($row1["status"] == "3") 
    {
    $status = "Pending";
    }
    if ($row1["status"] == "4") 
    {
    $status = "Closed";
    }
    if ($row1["status"] == "5") 
    {
    $status = "Denied";
    }
    $id = $row1["id"];
    $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM callback WHERE lead_id=$id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
   $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);
    if ($result2)
    {
    while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2))
    {


    $data[] = array(
    "Created" => $row1["curdate"], 
    "Customer Name" => $row1["cname"], 
    "Designation" => $row1["designation"],
    "Contact" => $row1["number"],
    "Company" => $row1["company"],
    "Address" => $row1["street"],
    "Landmark" => $row1["landmark"],
    "Zip" => $row1["zip"],
    "Products" => $row1["product"],
    "Last Callback" => $row2["callback"],
    "Last Visit" => $row2["vdate"],
    "Status" => $status
   );
   }
   }
   else
   {
    $data[] = array(
   "Created" => $row1["curdate"], 
    "Customer Name" => $row1["cname"], 
    "Designation" => $row1["designation"],
    "Contact" => $row1["number"],
    "Company" => $row1["company"],
    "Address" => $row1["street"],
    "Landmark" => $row1["landmark"],
    "Zip" => $row1["zip"],
    "Products" => $row1["product"],
    "Last Callback" => "NULL",
    "Last Visit" => "NULL",
    "Status" => $status
    );
    }
    }
```

What am i doing wrong? Also i'm a noob at this so, please go easy on me thanks.

Comment: `mysqli_query()` only returns false if the query fails to run, not if it doesn't find any rows.

Comment: I would recommend trying to use 1 SQL statement with a simple LEFT JOIN rather than using multiple statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$result2` is a `mysqli_result` object, you can't use it in an `if` statement. You should use its [`num_rows`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) property instead i.e.

```
if ($result2->num_rows > 0)
```

(in place of `if ($result2)`)

Comment: Hey, That worked! Thanks for explaining ! You're the best. Cheers :D